# Javascript tx.executeSql() hit TypeError : type error

Tags: javascript, ibm-mobilefirst, web-sql

I'm testing a migrated hybrid apps from MobileFirst v7 to v8.

Now I get "TypeError" when I try to execute a update statement:

```
var db = openDatabase();
var addr1 = document.getElementById('Addr1').value;
var addr2 = document.getElementById('Addr2').value;
var addr3 = document.getElementById('Addr3').value;
var id = document.getElementById('Id').value;

db.transaction(function (tx) {
    sqlupdate= "UPDATE Profile SET Addr1 = '" + addr1 + "', ";
    sqlupdate= sqlupdate + " Addr2 = '" + addr2 + "', ";
    sqlupdate= sqlupdate + " Addr3 = '" + addr3 + "' ";
    sqlupdate= sqlupdate + " where Id ='" + id + "'";

    tx.executeSql(sqlupdate,errorOn,successOn);
});

function errorOn()
{
    alert("Error");
}

function successOn()
{
    alert("Profile Saved");
}
```

[image]
[image]

I'm running tx.executeSql() for SELECT and INSERT with no problem, this error only happen when UPDATE.

Anyone can point out my mistake ?
Thanks.

Comment: I'm quite sure that the error handler will be called with some useful informations so use them instead of only alerting "Error"...

Comment: Hi Andreas, thanks for your suggestion, unforturnately the execution not even go into the errorOn callback. It just stop at the tx.executeSql() and the only information I have is the error message from the console.

Answer (score 0):

Ok... Finally i got the answer. The problem is from here :

```
tx.executeSql(sqlupdate,errorOn,successOn);
```

this function require 4 parameters and need to switch the callback's position :

```
tx.executeSql(sqlupdate,*[updateParams]*,successOn, errorOn);
```

so the solution is change the code to following :

```
db.transaction(function (tx) {
    sqlupdate= "UPDATE Profile SET Addr1 = ?, ";
    sqlupdate= sqlupdate + " Addr2 = ?, ";
    sqlupdate= sqlupdate + " Addr3 = ? ;
    sqlupdate= sqlupdate + " where Id =? ";

    tx.executeSql(sqlupdate,[addr1, addr2, addr3, id],successOn, errorOn);
});
```

for minimal code change, you can remain the sql and just put an empty array to make it work :

```
tx.executeSql(sqlupdate,[],successOn, errorOn);
```